# Spatial Regression of uniformly sampled KDE

Tags: regression, spatial, kernel-smoothing, weighted-regression, density-estimation

I'm trying to formulate a spatial regression, and could do with some guidance.

For my independent variable, I have multiple discrete observations, each with a latitude, a longitude, and a category. For my dependent variable, I have multiple observations with a a latitude and longitude.

I'd like to use my independent variables to predict the density of my dependent variable. To do this, I have split my independent variable by category (giving me multiple independent variables) and performed kernel density estimation on each split, and have then uniformly sampled the resulting KDE. I do the same with my dependent variable.

In doing this, I've ended up with a table with latitude, longitude, $Y$ (dependent variable) density, $X_1$ density, $X_2$ density, $X_3$ density... $X_n$ density (where $X$ represents the category of independent variable).

Using this table, I can build a normal OLS regression model, but in doing so I am throwing away my spatial information that could be useful to the model. I don't think it makes much sense to derive a spatial weight matrix using distance banding or KNN since my sampling is uniform... but equally, I'm not sure how handle my discrete observations.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. If it makes any difference, I'm using a combination of GeoDa for exploration and PySal for more repeatable analysis... but this is more of a theoretical than a practical question.

TL;DR: Is it possible to use the output of a regularly sampled KDE map to generate a spatial weighting matrix, and if not, how can I deal with my spatially discrete observations in formulating a regression model?